# HOW: YouTube API to fire Javascript event when Start Playing

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I am using  method to embed YouTube Videos in my website.

**I need to trigger a JavaScript function when a visitor sees my video.**

Basically, my videos are tutorial based.
And I want to trigger a Feedback form when the visitor sees the Video.

I am not sure when and how to trigger the Event ??!!
At the beginning of the video or at the end.

Please help me out.

Comment: You should show your code. It's very difficult to try to answer a question like this without code.

Answer (score 0):

check the [youtube api for javascript](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference):

> Your HTML pages that display the chromeless player must implement a callback function named onYouTubePlayerReady. The API will call this function when the player is fully loaded and the API is ready to receive calls". And possible states are:
>
> > onStateChangeThis event is fired whenever the player's state changes. Possible values are unstarted (-1), ended (0), playing (1), paused (2), buffering (3), video cued (5). When the SWF is first loaded it will broadcast an unstarted (-1) event. When the video is cued and ready to play it will broadcast a video cued event (5)."

```
 function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
    ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
 }

 function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
    alert("Player's new state: " + newState);
 }
```